# Grails application stops responding after every few hours

Tags: spring, tomcat, grails

I have a Grails web application deployed on tomcat 8 running on Windows. My database is sqlserver. 
The problem is that every few hours when I try to log into (spring security) this web application it stops responding. I can access the login page but when I enter username and password (first time the DB is hit) the application just stops responding, the browser waits for indefinite time. 
I am also using quartz plugin with version 1.0.2.

When I restart tomcat the application just works fine for few hours.

Comment: Looks like wrong/absent use of transaction management.

Comment: You get no error message or exception you can provide?  Also I have used Tomcat 7 and SQL Server very successfully you could try using Tomcat 7.  What does your Datasource.groovy look like and what version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the JDBC pool dies up. The same might also happen, if you put your PC in sleep and it depends on the DB/driver. Mysql doesn't survive the suspension, PostgreSQL does.

Check the logs btw. This is the 1st thing you should do

Comment: Where I can find logs when I start the app with: `java -Dgrails.env=production -jar /root/app-0.4.war > ~/app.out
`?

Comment: either in `~/app.out` or in the appender specified in your `logback.groovy`

Comment: ~/app.out was empty (just the start and address). No errors.